# Using the ForecastCombinations package with forecast package for univariate forecasting

Tags: r

I'm messing around with some of R's forecast capabilities and wanted to ensemble a few forecasts together. Using the forecast package, I did a number of univariate forecasts and now want to ensemble them using a weighting scheme. I like the approach taken by the ForecastCombinations combinations package, but can't seem to reproduce anything outside of the example in `?Forecast_comb`

Anyone have suggestions for this or have a better strategy for using an existing R package to weight the ensemble together.

Here was one attempt that obviously doesn't work.

```
y1 = rnorm(100)
fit1 = auto.arima(y1)
fit2 = ets(y1)
#fit3 = ma(y1, order=3)
forc1 = forecast(fit1, n=10)$mean
forc2 = forecast(fit2, n=10)$mean
#forc3 = forecast(fit3, n=10)$mean
forc_all = cbind(forc1,forc2)
forc_all = forc_all
forc_all

example0[[i]] <- Forecast_comb(obs = y1 ,
                               fhat = as.matrix(forc_all), Averaging_scheme = "best")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are training the forecasts, not on a validation set (10 out of sample observed values) but on the original observation used to create the forecast:

```
dim(y1)
dim(forc_all)
```

You need the 10 observed values so that R knows to compare `forc_all` columns with the out of sample observations. The idea is that out of the two columns, he would tell you which to use, going foreward. 
[Here](http://eranraviv.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/VIG3-1.pdf)
you can find a more extensive manual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your example is reproducible. Forgive me if I misunderstood your question, but I think you can make it work as:

```
library(forecast)
library(ForecastCombinations)

y1 = rnorm(100)
fit1 = auto.arima(y1)
fit2 = ets(y1)
#fit3 = ma(y1, order=3)
forc1 = forecast(fit1, n=10)$mean
forc2 = forecast(fit2, n=10)$mean
#forc3 = forecast(fit3, n=10)$mean
forc_all = cbind(forc1,forc2)
forc_all = forc_all
forc_all

fitted <- Forecast_comb(obs = y1 ,fhat = as.matrix(forc_all), Averaging_scheme = "best")$fitted

> fitted
           [,1]
 [1,] 0.1084883
 [2,] 0.1084883
 [3,] 0.1084883
 [4,] 0.1084883
 [5,] 0.1084883
 [6,] 0.1084883
 [7,] 0.1084883
 [8,] 0.1084883
 [9,] 0.1084883
[10,] 0.1084883
```